# Qgis2web (Leaflet) - Search Function: Zooming in on search results

Tags: qgis, leaflet, qgis2web

So I just made a nice Leaflet webmap in Qgis2web for work. The map shows the locations of all the projects we have worked on in the last few years as points, including information about which team worked on it, the clients and so on.

I included the search function where you can search different project-numbers, it works fine but I want the search function to zoom in on the search result, so its clear which point on the map is the result of your search (Sometimes two or more projects are in really close proximity). Does anyone have an idea on how to accomplish that?

Comment: I just found a way to do it! You just go into the "js" folder of your exported webmap, then open the "leaflet-search" file and change your zoom-value to whatever you want, in my case 20 worked perfectly (it was set to 0 before)

Comment: Please add your comment as an answer, it will help other people with the same issue